# ASP IF Logic not fully functioning

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a login form that checks for roles and when the credentials are met, the user is directed to a specific page. My issue is that when the username or password is incorrect, my logic fails to prompt the user via a label that I have in the design. I even tried implementing it via a Try/Catch and still the same result.

The Design:

```
<div><asp:Label ID="lblinfo" runat="server" Width="374px" CssClass="blktext"></asp:Label></div>
```

The code in behind the (button event-handler):

```
 Try
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
            con.Open()

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Check_Users", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            Dim p1 As New SqlParameter("Login_name", username.Text)
            Dim p2 As New SqlParameter("Login_Pwd", password.Text)

            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p2)
            Dim rd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            'check the Role of the user logging in'
            While (rd.Read())
                Session("numrecord") = rd.GetValue(0).ToString()
                rd.GetValue(11).ToString()

                If rd.HasRows Then
                    If rd.GetValue(11).ToString() = 1 Then
                        rd.Read()
                        lblinfo.Text = "You are Authorized."
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username.Text, True)
                        Response.Redirect("securepages/SecurePage.aspx")
                    Else
                        lblprompt.Text = "Invalid username or password."
                    End If
                    If rd.GetValue(11).ToString() = 2 Then
                        rd.Read()
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username.Text, True)
                        Response.Redirect("securepages/newShipment.aspx")
                    Else
                        lblprompt.Text = "Invalid username or password."
                    End If
                End If
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblprompt.Text = "Invalid username or password."
        End Try
```

Could I get some help as to what am failing to do here?

Comment: Using catch to handle expected behavior?  I'm guessing you also have clear text passwords in a database? Yikes!  It seems like you're reinventing the wheel when you could be using ASP.Net Membership and Authorization to do this automatically.

Comment: I don't understand why you are performing additional `rd.Read()` operations inside a `While (rd.Read())` loop. I also don't understand what the standalone line `rd.GetValue(11).ToString()` is doing. I further don't understand why you are taking a value, converting it to a string, and then comparing it to an integer value 1. And then, after you have read another record and redirected authorized users away, why you are performing another comparison with an integer value 2. Maybe it would help if you could show the rows returned by your procedure for authorized and unauthorized users?

Comment: ...if only I handled he DB part

Comment: AFAIK you can't write text out to the page THEN redirect. You need to redirect before you write content to the page. And it looks like you're trying to redirect twice, which won't work.

Comment: Youch.  Even if you don't have control of the database, at least write a data layer class that returns an object with every possibility of returned data from the stored procedure.  You got data, business, presentation, and flow logic in one method in the presentation layer.

Comment: What does the query returns? It seems strange to have a numrecord and doing multiple dr.Read(). Also, hash your password!

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, please write a basic POCO object to encapsulate the values from the data layer.

Use your datareader to POPULATE the Poco object, and insert some basic logic on the Poco object.
Use the datareader quickly, then get rid of it.

Then you could actually reuse the object and your logic.

Something like this.

Then (in the presentation layer) ~respond to the values in the Poco with the redirects and such.

```
public enum RedirectTypeEnum
{
    Unknown = 0,
    SecurePage = 1,
    NewShipment = 2,
}

public class LoginAttemptResult
{
    public LoginAttemptResult()
    {
        this.NumRecord = 0;
        this.ResultNumberAkaColumn11 = 0;
    }

    public int NumRecord { get; set; }
    public int ResultNumberAkaColumn11 { get; set; }
    public RedirectTypeEnum RedirectType
    {
        get
        {
            RedirectTypeEnum returnValue = RedirectTypeEnum.Unknown;
            if (this.ResultNumberAkaColumn11 == 1)
            {
                returnValue = RedirectTypeEnum.SecurePage;
            }
            if (this.ResultNumberAkaColumn11 == 2)
            {
                returnValue = RedirectTypeEnum.NewShipment;
            }
            return returnValue;

        }
    }

    public bool IsAuthorized
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.ResultNumberAkaColumn11 == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (this.ResultNumberAkaColumn11 == 2)
            {
                return false; /* ?? */
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'll have one place where you populate this object, and someone can see clearly what the biz logic is by looking at the POCO object.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that I see is that you are response.redirect'ing in a Try...Catch block. Unless you put `, False`  (which allows the code to finish executing instead of aborting) after the URL, you will throw a *Thread is aborting* error every time it attempts to redirect.

As for the message not showing, you show how **lblinfo** is created, but what about **lblprompt**? Perhaps you have its `visible` property set to false? If this is the case, make sure to change it to true in the code. Also, make sure you are not clearing its value on events such as page_load.

I have also cleaned up the code a little bit and implemented a datatable object instead of the reader:

```
    Try
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Check_Users", New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("Login_name", username.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("Login_Pwd", password.Text))

        Dim sqlDataAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dtResults As New DataTable
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dtResults)

        lblprompt.Text = "Invalid username or password."
        'check the Role of the user logging in'
        If dtResults.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            With dtResults.Rows(0)
                Session("numrecord") = .Item(0).ToString()

                If .Item(11).ToString() = 1 Then
                    lblprompt.Text = ""
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username.Text, True)
                    Response.Redirect("securepages/SecurePage.aspx", False)
                ElseIf .Item(11).ToString() = 2 Then
                    lblprompt.Text = ""
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username.Text, True)
                    Response.Redirect("securepages/newShipment.aspx", False)
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblprompt.Text = "An error has occurred." & ex.Message
    End Try
```